# Google fusion table latitude,longitude instead of location

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I have used fusion table layer query to retrieve places using the `Location` column,

```
   layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Location',
        from: '****************************',
        where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(\'Location\', CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + position.lat() + ', ' + position.lng() + '),' + 5000 + '))',
        limit: 500
    }
});
```

As given in google,
[image]

How we have to use the `latitude, longitude` to query the places instead of `location` in `select and where condition`.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What does your table look like?  Do you have a single column comma separated (latitude,longitude) or two columns?  What are the names of those columns?

Comment: My table have two columns named `Latitude` and `Longitude`. I want use them instead of using a postal code in `select` and where `condition`.

Comment: If I recall correctly you just use the name of the first column, the one defined as latitude, which in your case would probably be `Latitude`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For a two column latitude/longitude use the name of the first column, the one defined as latitude, which in your case would be `Latitude`.